# Found nil while unwrapping an optional value while setting textColor of label

Tags: swift3, label, iboutlet

I am new in ios and I am making an app using XCode 9.2 with swift 3.2.I am facing a problem which is i am setting textColor of label but it show an error which is: Found nil while unwrapping an optional value in line titleBar.textColor = UIColor.white
    this happens for all IBOutlet in viewController of this class but in same project other view controller work fine Please help me.
    My code is :

```
    @IBOutlet weak var titleBar: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleBar.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the app crash or found nil is the @IBOutlet is not connected with the storyboard.. somehow the @IBOutlet connection is broken... please check and connect it and then try the code.

*After the connection is done you can use this code -

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleBar: UILabel! {
   didSet {
   titleBar.textColor = UIColor.white
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `self.titleBar.textColor = UIColor.white` and also make sure that you have properly bind the IBOutlet in to your class file